# Hadoop - job submission time on large data

Tags: dictionary, hadoop, reduce

Did anyone face any problem with submitting job on large data. Data is around 5-10 TB uncompressed, it is in approximate 500K files. When we try to submit a simple java map reduce job, it's mostly spend more than hour on getsplits() function call. And takes multiple hour to appear in job tracker. Is there any possible solution to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

with 500k files, you are spending a lot of time tree walking to find all these files, which then need to be assigned to list of InputSplits (the result of getSplits).

As Thomas points out in his answer, if your machine performing the job submission has a low amount of memory assigned to the JVM, then you're going to see issues with the JVM performing garbage collection to try and find the memory required to build up the splits for these 500K files.

To makes matters worse, if these 500K files are splittable, and larger than a single block size, then you'll get even more input splits to process the files (a file of size say 1GB, with a block size of 256MB, you'll by default get 4 map tasks to process this file, assuming the input format and file compression supports splitting the file). If this is applicable to your job (look at the number of map tasks spawned for your job, are there more than 500k?), then you can force less mappers to be created by amending the `mapred.min.split.size` configuration property to a size larger then the current block size (setting it to 1GB for the previous example means you'll get a single mapper to process the file, rather than 4). This will help the performance of getSplits method the resultant list of getSplits will be smaller, requiring less memory.

The second symptom of your problem is the time is takes to serialize the input splits to a file (client side), and then the deserialization time at the job tracker end. 500K+ splits is going to take time, and the jobtracker will have similar GC issues if it has a low JVM memory limit.

Answer (score 0):

It largely depends on how "strong" your submission server is (or your laptop client), maybe you need to upgrade RAM and CPU to make the getSplits call faster.

I believe you ran into swap issues there and the computation takes therfore multiple times longer than usual.